# Where to find the JSR 223 TCK

Tags: java, sun, jsr223

I am looking for a place to find (download link or so) the TCK of JSR 223 specification.
This is for a project which released under Apache 2 license.
(actually I want the source code + the binary of TCK for me to understand the spec well, even source code is enough worst case)

Thanks

Comment: Did you try Google? http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr223/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it redirects to java partner site which ask credentials from a company.

Answer (score 0):

Many TCKs are proprietary items available only via license to <del>Sun</del> Oracle. You can't just download them. At Apache, those project with TCK access keep them in restricted locations and only make them available to people who are willing to sign the NDA.